# EF Code First keyless association

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I've got a database that I control part of and have no control over another part.  I'd like to use EF to access both parts, but I'm having trouble declaring some of the relationships.  Consider the following two entities:

```
   public class AnswerSet {
      public AnswerSet() { WeeklyAnswerSets=new HashSet<WeeklyAnswerSet>(); }
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string StudentCode { get; set; }
      public string InstructorCode { get; set; }
      public string AssignedDateOrig { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<WeeklyAnswerSet> WeeklyAnswerSets { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<INSTSTUD> InstStuds { get; set; }
   }

   public class INSTSTUD {
      [Key]
      public int FOCLIST { get; set; }
      public string ININSCD { get; set; }
      public string INSTUCD { get; set; }
      public string ASSIGNEDDATE { get; set; }
   }
```

I can control AnswerSet but not INSTSTUD.  And INSTSTUD.FOCLIST will not be usable as a permanent foreign key in AnswerSet.  Instead, if I want to look up an INSTSTUD from an AnswerSet, I'll need to use a join like this: `StudentCode=INSTUCD and InstructorCode=ININSCD and AssignedDateOrig=ASSIGNEDDATE`.

So given these constraints, what can I put in `OnModelCreating` so that my navigation property `AnswerSet.InstStuds` will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, is you can't.  If you don't have a permanent primary key, then you can't use a navigation property.  You will have to do your joins manually, and hope there are no key violations.